# Optimize apache/php for CURL crawler with multi curls

Tags: php, apache, optimization, curl

I'm running multi curl crawler with 500 open connections all time.
Do you have any advices for apache/php settings in order to get best performance?

This is my settings:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          50
    MinSpareServers       50
    MaxSpareServers      100
    MaxClients          1500
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your crawler with a small limit of process and then run this script

```
ps -C httpd,apache2,apache -o rss --no-header | awk '{a=a+$1; b=b+1} END {print a" "a/b" "b}'
```

it will show you an average use of memory per apache process.. then you can calculate how many processes do you have on limit for your structure based on your ram.

Comment: I can anticipate that your MaxRequestsPerChild will affect too much the memory.. set it to 10 or 100... and set ServerLimit to 1500. ps, sorry the poor english

Comment: That command gave me this result "640600 12319.2 52" but I don't understand what that means ???

Comment: 640Mb total, 12,3 Mb per process, 52 processes ;)

Comment: So, what should I change in Settings? In my case CPU is overloading to 98%, but memory only 50%

Comment: are you using php 5.5 or APC module on earlier phps? it will help

Comment: PHP is 5.4.6 without APC…I don't have visitors on that server, it is only crawling all around. I think that APC won't help in this much. What do you think?

Comment: it "compiles" to some sort of bitcode... you will have "compile overhead" just once..